# Appending value from a row onto the same row but in a new column when condition in for loop is met

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, append

I need to attach the numeric values, whichever is less, from columns, R2ESL or MCL, into a new column, Lesser Value, for each row (ex. A, B, C).

For example, for param A, MCL with value of 7 is less than R2ESL with value of 10. I want to get 7 into a new column (Lesser Value), but on the same row (A).

So far, I have only been able to use 'append' in a for-loop to attach the Limiting Criteria column.

| param | R2ESL | MCL | Limiting Criteria | Lesser Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 7 | MCL | 7 |
| B | 100 | 150 | R2ESL | 100 |
| C | 55 | 55 | equal | 55 |

```
excel_df = pd.read_excel('ESLs_MCL_Comparison_copy.xls')

# Changing data type in columns to float
R2ESL_float = [float(item) for item in R2ESL]
print(R2ESL_float)

MCL_float = [float(item) for item in MCL]
print(MCL_float)

# Comparing the values in each column
result = []
result2 = []
for (R2ESL_float, MCL_float) in zip(R2ESL_float, MCL_float):
    if R2ESL_float > MCL_float:
        result.append("R2ESL")
        # result2.append(param_row_value_R2ESL) <-- Need help here
    elif R2ESL_float < MCL_float:
        result.append("MCL")
        # result2.append(param_row_value_MCL) <-- Need help here
    elif R2ESL_float == MCL_float:
        result.append("Equal")
        # result2.append("param_row_value_MCL_or_R2ESL") <-- Need help here
    else:
        result.append("null")
        # result2.append("null")

excel_df["Limiting Criteria"] = result
# excel_df["Lesser Value"] = result2
print(excel_df)
```

I am new to python and have only been learning for a few weeks, so please explain clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
v1, v2 = df['R2ESL'].values, df['MCL'].values
df['Limiting Criteria'] = np.select([v1==v2, v1<v2, v1>v2], ['equal', 'R2ESL', 'MCL'])

# Determine the lesser value
df['Lesser Value'] = df[['R2ESL', 'MCL']].min(axis=1)
```

For example (this is copied from an interactive Python session):

```
>>> df
  param  R2ESL  MCL
0     A     10    7
1     B    100  150
2     C     55   55


>>> v1, v2 = df['R2ESL'].values, df['MCL'].values
>>> df['Limiting Criteria'] = np.select([v1==v2, v1<v2, v1>v2], ['equal', 'R2ESL', 'MCL'])
>>> df
  param  R2ESL  MCL Limiting Criteria
0     A     10    7               MCL
1     B    100  150             R2ESL
2     C     55   55             equal


>>> df['Lesser Value'] = df[['R2ESL', 'MCL']].min(axis=1)
>>> df
 param  R2ESL  MCL Limiting Criteria  Lesser Value
0     A     10    7               MCL             7
1     B    100  150             R2ESL           100
2     C     55   55             equal            55
```

What it does:

For `Limiting Criteria`:

1. `.values` returns the numpy array behind the Series (or DataFrame)
2. `[v1==v2, v1<v2, v1>v2]` creates a list of three numpy arrays containing only boolean values (so-called "masks"). The first contains True's where the item in `v1` and `v2` are equal, False's otherwise. The second contains True's where the value in `v1` is less than the value in `v2`. The third contains True's where the value in `v1` is greater than `v2`.
3. `np.select` takes two parameters: a list of "conditions" (really masks), and a list of values, and replaces True's in each condition with the corresponding value from the list of values

For `Lesser Value`:

1. `df[['R2ESL', 'MCL']]` basically selects a subset dataframe of the original dataframe, with only the columns `R2ESL` and `MCL`.
2. `.min(axis=1)` gets the minimum value of all the columns for each row.